# Browser video flickers when switching clip [HTML, JS]

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I want to have video clips that seamlessly transition from one to another(with idle animations). For starters, I wanted to use the normal browser player and just switch sources when one clip ends like this:

```
var videos = [
    "video/1.webm",
    "video/2.webm",
    "video/3.webm",
    "video/4.webm",
];
let i = 0;
const videoCount = videos.length;
const element = document.getElementById("video");
element.addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);

function myHandler() {
    i++;
    if (i == videoCount) {
        i = 0;
    }
    element.setAttribute("src", videos[i]);
    element.autoplay = true;
    // element.preload = true;
    // element.muted = true;
    element.load();
}
```

The problem is that there is a stutter/flicker or delay before a new clip starts playing(in chrome and firefox). The clips I have don't contain any black or empty frames(clips I have loop fine).

As far as I can tell it shows a blank screen for a frame or two.

Is there any way to preload the clips so they switch instantaneously?

Comment: My first attempt would be to put each video in a div stacked on top of each other. When one video ends, hide the div and start the next video.

Comment: Just two video objects is enough, one to play while other loads. Use `zIndex` in javascript to put the current playing one **on a layer above the loading one** (for next video, so the loader is hidden), on detecting a video end event you switch layers and play new one, the ended video tag becomes a loader for next file.

Answer (score 1):

The comments from [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234/will) and [VC.One](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057709/vc-one) were leading me onto the right path. I created 2 video elements and instead of pushing and pulling the z-index I pushed it off screen with:

```
.hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100vw;
}
```

I ended up using this:

```
var videos = [
    "video/v1.webm",
    "video/v2.webm",
    "video/v3.webm",
    // ...
];
var i = 0;
const videoCount = videos.length;
const v1 = document.getElementById("video");
const v2 = document.getElementById("video2");
v1.muted = true;
v2.muted = true;

v1.setAttribute("src", videos[i]);
v1.load();
v1.play();
i++;
v2.setAttribute("src", videos[i]);
v2.load();

v1.addEventListener('ended', vHandler, false);
v2.addEventListener('ended', vHandler, false);

function vHandler() {
    if((i+1) == videoCount)
        i = 0;
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        i++;
        v2.setAttribute("src", videos[i]);
        v2.load();
        v1.classList.remove("hidden");
        v2.classList.add('hidden');
        v1.play();
    } else {
        i++;
        v1.setAttribute("src", videos[i]);
        v1.load();
        v2.classList.remove("hidden");
        v1.classList.add('hidden');
        v2.play();
    }
}
```